# Angularjs call a function from a controller to another controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I'm trying since few hours to call a function from a controller to another controller.

I saw similar topics (I tried but I'm certainly too bad):
[What's the correct way to communicate between controllers in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252780/whats-the-correct-way-to-communicate-between-controllers-in-angularjs)
[Can one controller call another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another)

But no concrete example like I'm looking for.

Controllers:

```
app.controller('Controller1', function($scope, $modal, $modalInstance, job, JobServices) {

   $scope.job1 = function () {
       JobServices.job1($scope.name)
       .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // something
       });
   }


   function doSomething(){
      // How call test() from controller2 ?
   }
}

app.controller('Controller2', function($scope){
   function test(){
      do a lot of things
   }
}
```

What's the best and easiest way to do that ?

Thank you a lot

EDIT:

I already tried using something like that:

```
app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope, $modal, $modalInstance, job, JobServices) {
```

But I have error saying job1 is undefined...

Comment: You probably want to put your logic into a [service/factory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28337130/8495123) and call the function on it instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$on and $broadcast in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446755/on-and-broadcast-in-angular)

Comment: My problem is I have a lot of errors when I use function($scope, $modal, $modalInstance, job, JobServices) to ['$scope', '$rootscope', function($scope, $rootscope, $modal, $modalInstance, job, JobServices) from my functions like job1 (see my edit)

Answer (score 1):

you could the $scope.$emit and $scope.$on, little bit like this

```
app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', '$rootScope' function($scope) {
   function doSomething(){
       $rootScope.$emit("callController2", {});
   }
}

app.controller('Controller2', ['$scope', '$rootScope' function($scope) {
  $rootScope.$on("callController2", function(){
    this.test();
  });
  function test(){
    do a lot of things
        }
}
```

Comment: As I said upper I already tried that and I have error (saying it's undefined) using ['$scope', '$rootScope'... (see my edit)